# I need to dynamically modify my drawables programatically

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-button

I have to apply a drawable to a button but here what is happening the very first time before I click my button the button drawable always comes as R.drawable.up even if the condition is Condition b.

```
int btnDrawable = R.drawable.up;

if(Condition a){
  btnDrawable = R.drawable.up;
}
else if(Condition b){
  btnDrawable = R.drawable.down;
}

mbtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(btnDrawable));
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example such that we can help you troubleshoot the problem that you're facing.

Comment: Either none of the Conditions are true or both are true. Just try to debug both Conditions.

Comment: Lets take this as an example I have a popup dialog and when I open it then the condition is "b" so there is a button which should carry the "down" drawable but in this case it is always showing the button "up" drawable until I touch it which also has same set of condition inside onTouch method.

Comment: Do you mind posting the Conditions a and b as well ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be just that `Condition a` is true as well, so it never checks `Condition b`

Have you tried debugging? (Click on the right of the line with the first if, then run bu clicking a bug icon next to run icon. Once code stops, check the values of `condition a` and `condition b`)

Comment: My onTouch method has the same conditions as above so when I touch the button it carries the correct drawable but why initially I am getting it wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is is that the first click has `a` as true and very click after that has `a` as false and `b` as true, but does not change background of that view?

Answer (score 0):

put

```
if(Condition a){
  btnDrawable = R.drawable.up;
}
else if(Condition b){
  btnDrawable = R.drawable.down;
}

mbtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(btnDrawable));
```

in `onClick()` or `onTouch()` method. It *should* work. Also, as @Miku said, maybe the condition a is always true, you might want to attach a debugger and checking it.

*In case it still won't work, I'd suggest you to paste the *full code*.

Comment: No actually I had to initialize that btnDrawable with a value somewhere else it gave me a compile time error of not being initialized.

Comment: that's why you *should* mostly post the full code, so the people would find an error way faster. From just the snippet you posted, the code could be anywhere from onCreate all the way to onDestroy, for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

I was placing the above code on the wrong place now I called this code while setting my view and it worked fine for me